# How to extract query parameters from URL of form `example.com/path#p1=v1&p2=v2...` in Angular

Tags: javascript, url, angularjs

I'm getting callbacks (from singly.com) in the form or URLs like
`example.com/path#p1=v1&p2=v2...`

What would be the Angular way to extract the query parameters? `$location.search` and `$routeParams` don't seem to work, I'm guessing due to the lack of the `?` in the URL.

Update: I have achieved my objective by manually attacking the URL via absUrl() but I'd like to know if there is a more Angular way of achieving the objective.

Comment: have you refered to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values/3855394#3855394

Comment: Could use something like `location.hash.split('&');`

Comment: Please see my update above.

Answer (score 0):

Ported from and based upon: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3855394/1250044

```
var queryHash = function (hash) {
    hash = (hash || location.hash).slice(1).split("&");
    var b = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < hash.length; ++i) {
        var p = hash[i].split("=");
        if (p.length !== 2) continue;
        b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    return b;
};

console.log( queryHash() );
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/xTSaV/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it isn't really answering how to do this 'the Angular way'.